# Room Database, inadvertantely changed table name during migration

Tags: database, kotlin, android-room

Working on an app in Kotlin, using Room. Previously, the table name was "favoritelist" as a string. I moved all API info and database strings to const val. After doing so, I accidentally changed the table name to "favoriteslist". I received reports that the app was crashing after the newest update. How can I get the database table corrected to avoid further crashes? Should I rename it, auto migrate to new version, then release?

Answer (score 0):

You have two potential fixes to cater for. Those who have migrated and those who have newly installed the App.

For the latter the App is probably working fine, but they will be using the newer table name.

For those who have migrated, the crash should have been post migration, after which the comparison against the compiled hash of the schema (what Room **expects**), is compared with the actual schema that was **found**.

If this is the case then changes to the database should be rolled back, as if the migration never happened.

Your next decision will be which table name is going to be used. This would be a factor in determining the conditions.

If the crash is as suggested above then you could just use the newer name and have a migration that renames the table from the older to the newer name. But this being a newer version of the App. In which case there would be no Room migration needed for the newer users.

If you want to revert to the original table name, then you would have to rename the table for the new users and the older users could continue but the migration would have to detect or handle the fact that there will be no newer table name for older users.

Obviously the most important factor is that you thoroughly test the scenarios before publishing the App.

**Example**

The Entity in question being (along with some constants) :-

```
const val DATABASE_NAME = "the_database.db"
const val DATABASE_VERSION = 3
const val FAVOURITES_TABLE_NAME = "favouritelist" /*  "favouriteslist"*/
const val incorrect_table_name = "favouriteslist"
const val FAVOURITES_ID_COLUMN = FAVOURITES_TABLE_NAME + "_id"

const val FAVOURITES_DESCRIPTION_COLUMN = FAVOURITES_TABLE_NAME + "_desc"

@Entity(tableName = FAVOURITES_TABLE_NAME)
data class Favourite(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = FAVOURITES_ID_COLUMN)
    var id: Long?=null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = FAVOURITES_DESCRIPTION_COLUMN)
    var description: String
)
```

When first run at version 1 `DATABASE_VERSION = 1` rather than `DATABASE_VERSION = 3` on one of two devices (no data added just forced and open)

Then when going to Version 2 `DATABASE_VERSION = 2`

```
const val FAVOURITES_TABLE_NAME = "favouritelist" /*  "favouriteslist"*/
```

was changed to

```
const val FAVOURITES_TABLE_NAME = /*"favouritelist"*/  "favouriteslist"
```

and then run on both devices.

The second device ran OK, reflecting a new install of the App.

The first device failed with the ***expected but found*** and the database was rolled back.

So the situation is the old install on the first device is still at version 1 and the new install on the second device is at version 2.

**The Fix** (to retain the original names)

Version 3 will correct that. So There needs to be two corrective actions:-

- for device 1 still on version 1 then effectively the migration from 1 to 3 needs to be skipped.
- for device 2 the migration has to rename the tables (and due to the inclusion of the table name in the column names, the columns have to be renamed)

**Device 1** aka (1 to 3)
Automigration is perhaps possible but it complained and appeared to want to change to version so it could then change to version 3 (because it progresses through the stored (exported) schemas).
Rather than mess around, knowing that nothing really needs to be done, a manual migration for 1 to 3 was added :-

```
.addMigrations(Migration(1,3){})
```

**Device 2** aka (2 to 3) first :-

```
@RenameColumn(incorrect_table_name, incorrect_table_name+"_id", toColumnName = FAVOURITES_ID_COLUMN)
@RenameColumn(incorrect_table_name, fromColumnName = incorrect_table_name+"_desc", toColumnName = FAVOURITES_DESCRIPTION_COLUMN)
@RenameTable(fromTableName = incorrect_table_name, toTableName =  FAVOURITES_TABLE_NAME)
class am2to3 : AutoMigrationSpec
```

along with :-

```
@Database(
    entities = [Favourite::class],
    version = DATABASE_VERSION,
    autoMigrations = [
        AutoMigration(2,3, TheDatabase.am2to3::class)
    ]
)
```

- never changed as it never went to version 2

**Results**

**Device 1** (API 30) :-

[image]

**Device 2** (API 28) :-

[image]

i.e. now with favouritelist NOT favouriteslist (likewise column names changed accordingly)

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, that explains a little better than what my searching led me to.  Room has a @Rename to rename tables from old to new. Would that suffice for updating the other users?

Comment: @Drew added an example to the answer that retains the original table name when going to a new version.